# shorewall masquerading from tun0 to ppp0

Tags: iptables, shorewall

- First interface is ppp0 (pptp vpn)
- Second inteface is tun0 (openvpn)
- Third interface eth0 (default gw
  interface)

Openvpn is set to change default route on client for all packets to go through tun0 vpn, that part is working ok.

I would like to make all packets from tun0 go to ppp0 and get out from that interface (MASQ) but somehow they always end up on eth0 (default gw interface)

/etc/shorewall/masq

```
ppp0 tun0
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: masquerading is a form of NAT, it nothing to do with how your packets are routed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured that out,

/etc/shorewall/providers

```
ovpn 1      1      main            ppp0            detect          -               -
```

/etc/shorewall/masq

```
ppp0    tun0
```

/etc/shorewall/route_rules

```
tun0                    -                       ovpn       1000
```